# Trigger vs. Dependency Property precendence

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, triggers, dependency-properties

I've got a question about the precendence of dependency property value.
My .xaml looks lik the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfTests.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:WpfTests"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Style>
    <Style>
        <!--<Setter Property="Canvas.Background" Value="Gray"/>-->
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="local:MainWindow.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <!--<Setter Property="local:LeistenPfeil.Symbolfarbe" Value="Red"/>-->
                <Setter Property="local:MainWindow.Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                <Setter Property="local:MainWindow.BG" Value="Blue"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Style>

<Grid Background="{Binding BG,Mode=TwoWay}">
    <Button Content="ChangeBG" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="OnClick"/>
</Grid>
```

In my Codebehind I created the dependency property 'BG' like:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public Brush BG
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BGProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BGProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BG.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BGProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BG", typeof(Brush), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black));


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BG = Brushes.Green;
    }
}
```

So, on startup the background is set to black (Default of DP). When mouse is over the background changes to blue. When it comes to a change of the BG-property in my codebehind, the trigger does work, but its influence to the grid-background vanished. 
I've already read this article on MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The problem in my understanding is: Why does the trigger work while the BG-property has its default value and doesn't when it changes in code behind? => The highest precendence of the background is the local background-binding of the grid, so why does the trigger work at all?

How can I get the trigger working again, after a change of BG-property in code behind?

Comment: The binding `Background="{Binding BG,Mode=TwoWay}"` does not set the value of the BG property. Here BG is the source of a binding, not the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code change is actually deemed to be a *Local* change. From your linked page on MSDN:

> Local value. A local value might be set through the convenience of the "wrapper" property, which also equates to setting as an attribute or property element in XAML, **or by a call to the SetValue API using a property of a specific instance**. If you set a local value by using a binding or a resource, these each act in the precedence as if a direct value was set.

I have highlighted the relevant part that states that calling `SetValue` as you did (via your `BG` CLR property) will result in a *Local* change. As a *Local* change has higher precedence than a `Trigger`, it overrules the `Trigger` value.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :), I've already read this, but maybe I don't get the Point... Setting the default value of the dependency property in PropertyMetada is more or less a call to the SetValue of the property isn't it? And if that's the case, then the Trigger would have right from the beginning the lower precendece. I'm wondering if the Metadata-Setting to black is something different than a call to the SetValue?

Comment: Look again... the default property value comes last in the list: *Default value from dependency property metadata*. Therefore, everything else can override it.

Comment: Oh I have to had read this over, there it stands clearly...
Thank you very much! 
Is there a workaround, so that I can reactivate the trigger again?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
BG = Brushes.Green;
```

which sets a *local value* with higher precedence than a Trigger, you could write

```
SetCurrentValue(BGProperty, Brushes.Green);
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setcurrentvalue(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ... The SetCurrentValue method changes the effective value of the
>   property, but existing triggers, data bindings, and styles will
>   continue to work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :), my intention was to change the source of the property. When I press the button I would like the grid background to be green if the mouse is away and blue if the mouse is over.
So I can say either I can change my source in code behind and loose my trigger, or I can change the property with SetCurrentValue() but can't change the background to green in the long term. is that correct?